# Javascript-Search function interesting behavior in IE

Tags: javascript, php, html, internet-explorer

Im using a search function to search inside a table, and hide collumns which not contain the searchterm.

This works perfect in my project on Firefox,Opera, and Safari. But not in IE, the Search function is not working.

**JS:**

```
function doSearch() {

var searchText = document.getElementById('searchTerm').value.toLowerCase(),
    table = document.getElementById('dataTable'),       
    text = (document.body.textContent) ? 'textContent' : 'innerText', // Feature detection
    rows = table.rows, // Caching rows
    rLen = rows.length, 
    r, rowText, cells, cols, c;

for (r = 1; r < rLen; r++) { // Ignoring the first row
    if (rows[r].className.indexOf('search_for') < 0) {continue;} // className check
    rowText = '';
    cells = rows[r].cells; // Caching the cells
    cols = cells.length;
    for (c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
        rowText += cells[c][text];
    }
    rowText = rowText.toLowerCase();
    if (rowText.indexOf(searchText) < 0) {
        table.rows[r].style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        table.rows[r].style.display = 'table-row';
    }
}
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<table id="searchTerm">
<?php while($info = mysqli_fetch_array($data )): ?>
<tr id="tr_<?php echo $info['ID'];?>" class="search_for">
<td><?php echo $info['text'];?></td>
</tr>
<tr id="detail_tr_<?php echo $info['ID'];?>" >
<td>detail text....</td>
</tr>
<?php endwhile; ?>
<tr id="test"><td>X</td></tr>
</table>
```

The php while will output a few rows.

So, what i found out.

the `rows = table.rows,` in the Javascript only notcices the `<tr>`'s which have an "detail_tr" as id, the normal ones "tr_" dont get noticed.

another very strange thing is, in Debbuger from IE, i can see what "rows" contains.

`<tr>` with an "detail_tr" get detected as `[objectHTMLTableRowElement]`
`<tr>` with the "test" as id, gets detected as `[objectHTMLCollection]`

I added an image, in the upper part you can see the debugger, and in the lower part you see html explorer : http://postimg.org/image/94leleccj/

What could be the Problem here?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/35cQQ/) of your code and it's working quite fine in IE9+

**JavaScript:**

```
function doSearch() {
    var searchText = document.getElementById('searchTerm').value.toLowerCase(),
        table = document.getElementById('dataTable'),       
        text = (document.body.textContent) ? 'textContent' : 'innerText', // Feature detection
        rows = table.rows, // Caching rows
        rLen = rows.length, 
        r, rowText, cells, cols, c;

    for (r = 1; r < rLen; r++) { // Ignoring the first row
        if (rows[r].className.indexOf('search_for') < 0) {continue;} // className check
        rowText = '';
        cells = rows[r].cells; // Caching the cells
        cols = cells.length;
        for (c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
            rowText += cells[c][text];
        }
        rowText = rowText.toLowerCase();
        if (rowText.indexOf(searchText) < 0) {
            table.rows[r].style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('detail_' + table.rows[r].id).style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            table.rows[r].style.display = 'table-row';
            document.getElementById('detail_' + table.rows[r].id).style.display = 'table-row';
        }
    }
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" id="searchTerm" /> <button onclick="doSearch()">doSearch()</button>

<table id="dataTable">
    <tr><th>table</th></tr>
    <tr id="tr_1" class="search_for">
        <td>bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="detail_tr_1" >
        <td>foo bar</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr_2" class="search_for">
        <td>baz</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="detail_tr_2" >
        <td>foo baz</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="test"><td>X</td></tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you for the effort, i fixed the problem my self, in CSS, the `<tr>` was set to `display:block` and it looks like, IE has e problem with that...after changing it to 'table-row' it works now¨!